# Find out where "Text is read only" coming from

Tags: debugging, error-handling

My workflow involves converting a huge generated org-mode document that is created in a read only buffer and is automatically put together. When trying to export it to latex, sporadically I get the "Text is read only" error which is apparently hidden behind some `unwind-protect` somewhere because `toggle-debug-on-error` does not catch it. I have no good way of debugging this because I can't reproduce it for small documents so finding out the stacktrace of the error feels like the right way to go.

So my question is: is it possible to tell `toggle-debug-on-error` to also collect errors that are behind `unwind-protect`? I assume there are many such errors that are thrown and siletly handled during the process of export so I assume the feature I am looking for would *collect* rather than *immediately show me* the stack traces of the errors it encounters.

Note that while my problem is specific to org-mode and I would accept an answer that solves the particular one, I would appreciate an answer that helps me find the actual stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the question the answer occured to me but I finished writing it for posterity: `unwind-protect` does not inhibit errors caught by `debug-on-error`, only `condition-case` does, which I don't know how to override but fortunately this was not the case for me, the error is ignored due to the value of `debug-ignored-errors` containing the symbol `buffer-read-only`. Removing that from the variable allowed the error handler to show me the stack trace.

As for the actual problem, the issue was that org babel was trying to evaluate my code blocks.

Comment: It’s always nice when the answer pops into your brain like that! :) Make sure you don’t forget to accept your own answer.